# Unique row values skip the header in csv

Tags: bash, awk, sort, csv

I'm trying to find all the unique values in a column. However, with this command I'll also get the header row. How do I skip that?

```
awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")|","' '{if ($2!~/NULL/) {print $2}}' Files/* | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | wc -l
```

Sample data is as:

```
"link","shared_story","101","52
"link","published_story","118","100
"link","published_story","134","51
"link",NULL,"152","398
"link","shared_story","398","110
```

Comment: Is `Sample data` your sample input or expected output? I thought it was sample input but then you talk about a "header row" in your question and that doesn't seem to be present in your "Sample data". Whichever it is, input or output, please [edit] your question to add the other one too.

Comment: Also: 1) in your `FPAT` definition you have `("[^"]+")|","` - what string are you trying to match with `","` that isn't matched with `"[^"]+"`? 2) The last field on each line of your "Sample data" starts with a double quote but has no terminating double quote - is that **really** what your data looks like? If not then please fix your example.

Answer (score 2):

The line number of the current file in awk is stored in the special `FNR` variable (`NR` holds the line number overall, not per-file). So, if your header is on the first line, you can simply modify your command to skip that line:

```
awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")|","' '{if ($2!~/NULL/ && FNR>1) {print $2}}' Files/*
```

Alternatively, you can skip lines matching a specific string from your header:

```
awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")|","' '{if ($2!~/NULL/ && !/headerString/) {print $2}}' Files/*
```

Comment: @thanasisp thanks, Thanasi, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the whole task with one awk command like this:

```bsh
awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")|","' 'FNR > 1 && $2 !~ /NULL/ && !seen[$2]++ {cnt++}
                                    END {print cnt}' *.csv
```

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131217/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-with-awk-whilst-keeping-empty-lines) an example about this `awk` idiom, it is used to consider the value in the hash only for the first time we see it. So it is useful for various tasks, like, excluding duplicates, excluding uniques, allow only N times of appearence etc.

See also examples with the standard [awk built-in variables](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/), FNR is the record number per file (for one input file, `FNR==NR` for every line)

---

Also, in general, if you want to parse all the files excluding the first line, with any command, you could use `tail`. This excludes the first line of every file and prints the rest:

```bsh
tail -n +2 *.csv | command
```